# How to redirect spring logging to Weblogic log during context load?

Tags: spring, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a Weblogic application that uses spring.
The logs seem to be fine, except when I get errors during Spring context loading. This is the most critical point of logging for me, since I need to know what's wrong with the configuration.

How can I redirect org.springframework classes to log to my own file? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
#Redirect Spring errors to MSH.log

log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN, springLogs
log4j.appender.springLogs=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.springLogs.File=logs/MHS.log
log4j.appender.springLogs.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.springLogs.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.springLogs.layout.ConversionPattern=%nMessage: severity="%p" time="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}" threadId="%t"  location="%l" date="%d{MMM, dd yyyy}"
```

I also updated pom.xml to have spring framework use slf4j & log4j, as recommended in their blog post in http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/ :

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks.